# How to store data for future use in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, caching

I want to store my data fetched from web service in a label. How can I do that? I have used :

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

But, its not getting updated with the value.

Comment: Save your data in your local database. when u want to use, u can.

Comment: is there any other alternative? I do not want to create a local DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can save small amounts of data in `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *firstName = "Bob";
[defaults setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];

[defaults synchronize];
```

And retrieve it like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *firstName = [defaults stringForKey:@"firstName"];
```

Read more about NSUserDefaults [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you rather not use NSUserDefaults you can also use a property list like this:

```
NSArray *fruits = @[@"Apple", @"Mango", @"Pineapple", @"Plum", @"Apricot"];

NSString *filePathFruits = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fruits.plist"];
[fruits writeToFile:filePathFruits atomically:YES];

NSDictionary *miscDictionary = @{@"anArray" : fruits, @"aNumber" : @12345, @"aBoolean" : @YES};

NSString *filePathDictionary = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"misc-dictionary.plist"];
[miscDictionary writeToFile:filePathDictionary atomically:YES];

NSArray *loadedFruits = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: filePathFruits];
NSLog(@"Fruits Array > %@", loadedFruits);

NSDictionary *loadedMiscDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: filePathDictionary];
NSLog(@"Misc Dictionary > %@", loadedMiscDictionary);
```

See [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/data-persistence-and-sandboxing-on-ios--mobile-14078) article to get more information on different ways to persistently store data in iOS.

Comment: Its not any useName or Password. Its 2-3 labels like value of temperature etc in my home page. So is it good to use preferences this way for this use case?

Comment: The other option you would have if you do not want to use NSUserDefaults and you do not want to use a DB is to use a property list -- see above.

Comment: But yes, if you're only storing the value of different labels then NSUserDefaults or a Property list will do.